# Getting Data to Show up in My view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, model, asp.net-mvc-5

I've got a model and controller that is working, but my model is not showing any data inside the view. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

I have a single model that I am trying to pass with a couple variables inside it.

I am trying to use Html.ViewData.Model.(Variable name here). I keep getting a null exception even though I have hardset values in the model.

Any ideas

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;


namespace stuff
{
    public class BACnetModel
    {
        private string _rmNum = "Room Number";
        public string RmNum { get { return _rmNum; } set{_rmNum = value;} }

        private string _avRes = "70";
        public string AvRes { get { return _avRes; } set {_avRes = value;} }

        private string _bvRes = "T";
        public string BvRes { get { return _bvRes; } set { _bvRes = value; } }

        private string _mvRes = "O";
        public string MvRes { get { return _mvRes; } set { _mvRes = value; } }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class PEOController : Controller
    {

        //Set default values
        private string AvResult = "90";
        private string BvResult = "T";
        private string MvResult = "O";
        private string rmNum = "Room";

        // GET: PEO

        public ActionResult PEO(string BvResult, string AvResult, string MvResult, string rmNum)
        {

            var model = new BACnetModel
            {
                AvRes = AvResult,
                BvRes = BvResult,
                MvRes = MvResult,
                RmNum = rmNum
            };

            return View(model);
        }

        public ActionResult getRoomNumber(string roomNumber, ref uint BvInstance, ref uint AvInstance, ref uint MvInstance, out string rmNum)
        {
            switch (roomNumber)
            {
                case ("1B^1001^01"):
                    rmNum = "1B^1001^01";
                    BvInstance = 3000018;
                    AvInstance = 3000022;
                    MvInstance = 3000040;
                    break;

                case ("1B^1002^01"):
                    rmNum = "1B^1002^01";
                    BvInstance = 3000020;
                    AvInstance = 3000023;
                    MvInstance = 3000042;
                    break;

                default:

                    break;
            }
            rmNum = "Room";

            var model = new BACnetModel
            {
                AvRes = AvResult,
                BvRes = BvResult,
                MvRes = MvResult,
                RmNum = rmNum
            };


            return View(model);
        }

    }
```

View

```
@using  Stuff
@using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities
@model BACnetModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2> Stuff(PEO)</h2>
<p>
    Stuff
</p>
<label>Select a Room: </label>
<!-- I need to add Code that will loop through the database and provide rooms.
        I will need to provide a query that will be called on page load.-->

<form action="/PEO/getRoomNumber">
    <select id="roomList">
        <option value="1B^1001^01">1B^1001^01</option>
        <option value="1B^1002^01">1B^1002^01</option>
    </select><br/><br/>

    <fieldset id="peoFieldset">
        <legend>Room Results</legend>
        <label for="roomNumber">Room Number:</label>
        <input id="roomNumber" readonly="readonly"/>@Html.ViewData.Model.RmNum<br>
        <label for="rmSetpoint">Room Setpoint: </label>
        <input id="rmSetpoint" readonly="readonly" />@Html.ViewData.Model.AvRes<br>
        <label for="rmCode">Room Code: </label>
        <input id="rmCode" readonly="readonly" />@Html.ViewData.Model.BvRes<br>
        <label for="rmOcc">Room Occupancy: </label>
        <input id="rmOcc" readonly="readonly" />@Html.ViewData.Model.MvRes<br>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<label>Occupancy Value</label>
<select id="occValue">
    <option value="Occupied">Occupied</option>
    <option value="Unoccupied">Unoccupied</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your action is expecting various parameters, are you passing those to the action? Did you try to debug and see where does the exception happens?

Comment: Yes, I am actually in the process of switching over to using a form helper. I think the issue is the function is not being called properly. I need to clean up the function it seems.

Comment: Sorry to be harsh, but nothing makes sense here, in particular your view code (you are just creating arbitrary inputs that dont even have `name` attributes and would never post back anything) . Use strongly typed html helpers to generate you html so that you get 2 way model binding - @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RmNum)` etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are using ViewData in your view. Use the standard model binding rather. Try the following code in your view:

```
<fieldset id="peoFieldset">
    <legend>Room Results</legend>
    <label for="roomNumber">Room Number:</label>
    <input id="roomNumber" readonly="readonly"/>@Model.RmNum<br>
    <label for="rmSetpoint">Room Setpoint: </label>
    <input id="rmSetpoint" readonly="readonly" />@Model.AvRes<br>
    <label for="rmCode">Room Code: </label>
    <input id="rmCode" readonly="readonly" />@Model.BvRes<br>
    <label for="rmOcc">Room Occupancy: </label>
    <input id="rmOcc" readonly="readonly" />@Model.MvRes<br>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Tried that originally and it didn't work. Figured just keep changing stuff until something works :-D

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work.

First I created an instance of the model in the controller outside of any methods.

```
private BACnetModel model = new BACnetModel();
```

Once I did that, I then set the values of the model and returned them as part of the Action method.

```
public ActionResult PEO()
        {
            var Room1 =
                new SelectListItem {Text = "1B^1001^01", Value = "1B^1001^01"};
            var Room2 =
                new SelectListItem {Text = "1B^1002^01", Value = "1B^1002^01"};

            roomList.Add(Room1);
            roomList.Add(Room2);


            ViewBag.RoomList = new SelectList(roomList, "Text", "Value");

            model.RmNum = "";
            model.AvRes = "";
            model.BvRes = "";
            model.MvRes = "";


            return View(model);
        }
```

I then went to my view and put the Model values in the view.

```
<fieldset id="peoFieldset">
        <legend>Room Results</legend>
        <label for="roomNumber">Room Number:</label>
        <input id="roomNumber" readonly="readonly" value="@Model.RmNum" /><br>
        <label for="rmSetpoint">Room Setpoint: </label>
        <input id="rmSetpoint" readonly="readonly" value="@Model.AvRes" /><br>
        <label for="rmCode">Room Code: </label>
        <input id="rmCode" readonly="readonly" value="@Model.BvRes" /><br>
        <label for="rmOcc">Room Occupancy: </label>
        <input id="rmOcc" readonly="readonly" value="@Model.MvRes" /><br>
    </fieldset>
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: _"Works like a charm"_ **NOT** You need to go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials and try to understand the basics.

Comment: Actually, it works just like I need it to. So yes, it does work like a charm. :-D

Comment: No it does not - you clearly haven't even tried to POST the form yet. Go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials.

Comment: Actually it does, I am sitting here, running it in Debug. The purpose was to get the values from the model to show up. The values show up. The purpose was not to get a form, or anything to work. That is another question :-D

Comment: What on earth is the point of a form which can't be edited and can't be submitted. Even the fact that you create an instance of your model outside the action method is nonsense.  Please, please, go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials.

Comment: Dude, you know I'm messing with you. Hence the smiley faces. Seriously though, I know this is crap code. It's a dirty prototype. Once, I had it over to the dev team it will get productized. My job is to PoC stuff. I still say it does work though :-P